# How to remove a HKCU registry entry for all users on uninstall

Tags: windows-10, registry, windows-explorer, cloud-storage

I have an application that registers itself as a cloud storage provider on startup. The app is installed per machine. If two users on the same machine did use the app, both end up with registry entries under HKCU for the cloud storage provider entry in the explorer. So far, this is what I want.

Now, if **User A** *uninstalls* the app while **User B** is *not logged in*, **only the cloud storage provider entry for User A is removed**.

If **User B** is also logged in, the entries are removed for both.

**What can I do, to remove the entries for all users on this machine, regardless of their logged in state?**